# The mappings are inconsistent with each other

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping

I have problem with inconsistent mappings. I have in my application two entities - Contact (entity with contacts...) and Information, entities with informations to this contact (phones, emails, fax, websites etc.).

And In my Contact entity I made variables for each type, I need it in my application because this way is much easier:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany( targetEntity = "RelationInformations" , mappedBy = "objectID", cascade={"persist"} )
 */
protected $contactInformations;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany( targetEntity = "RelationInformations" , mappedBy = "objectID", cascade={"persist"} )
 */
protected $contactPhone;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany( targetEntity = "RelationInformations" , mappedBy = "objectID", cascade={"persist"} )
 */
protected $contactFax;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany( targetEntity = "RelationInformations" , mappedBy = "objectID", cascade={"persist"} )
 */
protected $contactWebsite;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany( targetEntity = "RelationInformations" , mappedBy = "objectID", cascade={"persist"} )
 */
protected $contactEmail;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany( targetEntity = "RelationInformations" , mappedBy = "objectID", cascade={"persist"} )
 */
protected $contactCommunicator;
```

And for example getter for phones looks like:

```
/**
 * Get contactPhone
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getContactPhone()
{
    if ($this->contactPhone !== null) {
        foreach ($this->contactPhone->toArray() as &$info) {
            if ($info->getType() !== RelationInformations::TYPE_TELEPHONE) {
                $this->contactPhone->removeElement($info);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->contactPhone;
}
```

This way i got only phones from my informations only by using this function so it's much easier in other places in application to get what I want.

RelationInformation Entity:

```
   /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column( name = "rnis_id" , type = "integer" , nullable = false );
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue( strategy = "AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\ManyToOne( targetEntity = "RelationContact" , inversedBy = "contactInformations" )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn( name = "rnis_object_id" , referencedColumnName="rnct_id", nullable = false );
 */
private $objectID;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column( name = "rnis_value" , type = "string" , nullable = false  )
 */
private $value;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column( name = "rnis_type" , type = "string" , nullable = false , length = 1 )
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\Column( name = "rnis_active" , type = "boolean" , nullable = false )
 */
private $active;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\Column( name = "rnis_default" , type = "boolean" , nullable = false )
 */
private $default;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column( name = "rnis_txt" , type = "string" , nullable = true )
 */
private $txt;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column( name = "rnis_type_private_business" , type = "integer" , nullable = true )
 */
private $typePrivateBusiness;
```

The problem is that in my profiler i can see errors like bellow. Application works correctly but I want to solve this issue.

```
The mappings RelationContact#contactPhone and RelationInformations#objectID are inconsistent with each other.
The mappings RelationContact#contactFax and RelationInformations#objectID are inconsistent with each other.
The mappings RelationContact#contactWebsite and RelationInformations#objectID are inconsistent with each other.
The mappings RelationContact#contactEmail and RelationInformations#objectID are inconsistent with each other.
The mappings RelationContact#contactCommunicator and RelationInformations#objectID are inconsistent with each other.
The mappings RelationContact#contactBrand and RelationInformations#objectID are inconsistent with each other.
```

Comment: please post the code of the Entity `RelationInformations`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't map the same `OneToMany` relations on the same `mappedby` key, so the beahviour of the doctrine mapping validation is to correctly pass the first `contactInformations` reference and fail on the other.

Try to map your entities as `One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table` as described in the [Doctrine2 doc reference](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table)

Hope this help

Comment: You gave me an idea how to solve it, I will try it right now and I will write when I will know something more ;-)

Comment: Everything looks okey but... When I have in my form collection mapped on 'contactPhone' for example. Phones appears correctly but when i Want to add phone i have an error that in 'ClassMetadata' there is no such key as contactPhone (because there is no relation now so this collection is not 'natural') . Any ideas Matteo  ? :-)

Comment: Look at the doctrine2 relations named as `One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table` and see if fulfil your requirements.

Comment: As I can see it will create another table only for relations or maybe I don't see something... ?

Comment: As described in the doc this will `enforces the one-to-many cardinality` so i hope this fix the doctrine mapping check

Comment: There is no way to do it without making another table ? This way I would have to create 6 new tables for each type of information so It's not great solution in my point of view.

Comment: Is there a way to inheritance annotation / mapping from another field in the same entity... ?